# Excel 2010 Pivot Formatting - Can't indent and wrap fields?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

When working with pivot tables in Excel 2010, I want to show my pivot in compact form, with each field being indented as you move through the data, like so:

[image: basic pivot structure]

However, some of my data strings are actually very long, and this significantly reduces the readability of the pivot, as seen here:

[image: really long data]

To correct, I thought I could simply resize the rows and wrap the text, but this causes the indentation to be removed automatically, like this:

[image: no more indent]

I've tried playing around with the few options I can think of to make this work. I *can* manually indent each field after wrapping, but any time the data is refreshed, this gets funky, with or without preserving formatting.

Is there a simple way I can make this work? Am I just stuck with one option (indentation) or the other (wrapping)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, yes this is possible! Sounds like a job for [pivot table](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)!

First things first, go to your Pivot Table Tools - Options - Actions - Select and make sure **Enable Selection** is *enabled*.

Next, go into your pivot table. When you move between fields you'll have a white plus sign type cursor and sometimes you'll get a **black down arrow**. When you get the arrow above the field you want to wrap, you click and it will select that Field.

Now, go to Home - Alignment - Wrap Text and it will wrap that field without getting rid of the pivot table structure.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. My problem was that I was setting the wrapping to the whole column/range of cells, not just the specific segment of the table.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've had this problem for years when vertically centering text and changing row height! Now I can make my PT's even  prettier! :)

Answer (score 0):

TAKE OFF FILTERS AS WELL
I've had this problem as well but, in addition to the solution above, I had to take off the filters I had on the pivot-table.

After that it the word-wrap formatting was preserved perfectly.

(To give credit, I found this solution after 30 minutes of googling from http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/three-tips-for-making-your-pivot-table-formatting-stick/)